# ruby open pathname with specified encoding

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to open files telling Ruby 1.9.3 to treat them as UTF-8 encoding.

```
require 'pathname'
Pathname.glob("/Users/Wes/Desktop/uf2/*.ics").each { |f|
  puts f.read(["encoding:UTF-8"])
}
```

The class documentation goes through several levels of indirection, so I am not sure I am specifying the encoding properly. When I try it, however, I get this error message

ICS_scanner_strucdoc.rb:4:in `read': can't convert Array into Integer (TypeError)
        from ICS_scanner_strucdoc.rb:4:in`read'
        from ICS_scanner_strucdoc.rb:4:in `block in <main>'
        from ICS_scanner_strucdoc.rb:3:in`each'
        from ICS_scanner_strucdoc.rb:3:in `'

This error message leads me to believe that read is trying to interpret the open_args as the optional leading argument, which would be the length of the read.

If I put the optional parameters in, as in puts f.read(100000, 0, ["encoding:UTF-8"]) I get an error message that says there are too many arguments.

What is the appropriate way to specify only the encoding? Would it be correct to say that this is an inconsistency between the documentation and the behavior of the class?

Mac OS 10.8
rvm current reports "ruby-1.9.3-p484"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you want to specify encoding for path name or for file itself.

If it is latter, this maybe what you want.

```
Pathname.glob("/Users/Wes/Desktop/uf2/*.ics").each { |f|
  puts File.open(f,"r:UTF-8")
}
```

With `Pathname.read` you can write like this.

```
Pathname.glob("/Users/Wes/Desktop/uf2/*.ics").each do |f|
  path = Pathname(f)
  puts path.read
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I am marking this as the solution. To accomplish exactly what I wanted, I needed to add a call to the IO read method like this:  `
Pathname.glob("/Users/Wes/Desktop/uf2/*.ics").each { |f|
  puts File.open(f,"r:UTF-8").read()
}'

Comment: I still wonder if this should be documented as a bug either in the documentation or in Ruby. I checked it again in Ruby 2.1.0 where I believe it says the Pathname::read should accept the "R:UTF-8" sring_arg. If I am correct can someone point me to the right place to submit the issue?

Comment: oh, I forgot to add `read` method to file io, that was my mistake.

Comment: And `Pathname.glob` is same as `Dir.glob` it returns list of paths, it's different with `Pathname.read'. I added a short example to my answer.